# How to set a contribution to another membership for the same member

Tags: civimember

Is there a way to set a contribution to another membership for the same member? He has 2 contributions and 1 active Membership without any contribution and 1 expired membership with 2 contributions including the renewed contribution?

Can I correct this?

Regards,

Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Membership Payment](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.membershippayment) extension for this.

This extension adds a new *Membership* field when editing a contribution.  You can use this to add, remove and move a contribution's association with a membership of that same contact.

See screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: thanks Jon for your answer